# Windows service stopped working after 1 day

Tags: c#, windows-services, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

I have created a windows service for scheduling cron jobs. Every 1 min that job is running. Everything is fine for one day.
The next day, my service is running fine. But all the cron jobs is not putting logs(doing nothing). If i restart my service, it starts working fine for the scheduling the cron jobs.

I wasn’t able to find any error log in windows event.

I have a same setup in UAT server. It is working fine continuously. But in the production environment it is stopping all my scheduling jobs without any log.

I need some expert advice on this. Please share your opinions.

Is there any environment policy issue? or any code level issue?

This is my code. This IncidentScanningJob is stopped without log.

```
 private ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;
 private IScheduler _scheduler;
 private ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactorypooling;
 private IScheduler _schedulerpooling;


 JobDataMap datamap = new JobDataMap();
                    datamap.Put(IncidentScaningJob.JobId, JobId);
                    datamap.Put(IncidentScaningJob._objeScheduler, _scheduler);
                    datamap.Put(IncidentScaningJob._objeSchedulerPooling, _schedulerpooling);
                    datamap.Put(IncidentScaningJob._objeCron, cron);
                    datamap.Put(IncidentScaningJob._objeIncidentProfileId, IncidentProfileId);

var scheduleDetail = JobBuilder.Create<IncidentScaningJob>()
         .WithIdentity(IncidentProfileId + "_ScheduleIncidentJob" + JobId, "_ScheduleIncidentJob" + JobId)
         .UsingJobData(datamap)
         .Build();

var ScheduleTaskflowJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                                 .WithIdentity(IncidentProfileId + "_ScheduleIncidentJob" + JobId, IncidentProfileId + "_GroupScheduleIncidentJob" + JobId)
                                                // .WithCronSchedule(cron, x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())                                                   
                                                .StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1))
                                                 .Build();
```

Comment: Without detailed knowledge about ( the code of) the service it is impossible for us to help.

Comment: You will need to go through the windows event logs looking for any oddities & add more logging code to your application to try & detect the point of failure.  Creating a Service that does something on a schedule is often a far worse alternative to using the built in Task Scheduler.

Comment: @PeterBons I have updated my question.

Comment: @AlexK. I have already gone through the even viewer. But nothing is useful.

Comment: Add more logging. Make sure you aren't quietly swallowing any exceptions. Take a look at _"Hangfire"_